# What does "禦姐" mean?

Tags: translation

I was reading a description of a web novel, and it said something about "禦姐/御姐", and I'm wondering what does it mean?

I know it is describing females, but what would be a good english translation?

Comment: "御" is the correct character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a loan word from Japanese Kanji word "御姉".

It's wildly used in ACG subculture. ACG is short for Anime (not animation), Comics (Manga actually) and Games. Now it has become ACGN with the addition of "Light Novel" which holds similar market niche in Asia like Twilight does in western.

Anyway, in those subculture, popular characteristics of "ideal" image of Asian girls are cuteness and petiteness. "御姉", in contrary, is used to describe females that can be characterized as sexy, mature.

To gain a more vivid impression, you can google pictures for 御姐/御姉 and compare the result with the result of 蘿莉/ロリ.

**!! Warning !!**

I just know these stuff based on my intellectual curiosity. Don't blame me if people call you a pervert if you keep saying these stuff to them.

Comment: ロリータ is that like Lolita?

Comment: @user3306356 I changed that it's more commonly referred as ロリ instead of ロリータ which is more close to Lolita e.g. the book or style. ロリ or ロリコン refers to Lolita Complex. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolicon for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not show some pics?
What I have shown following they all called 御姐/御姉.

They have such kinds of characteristics( for my opinion ):

1. In Weekdays/Working day, they take official uniforms, always in black color.
2. Make up obviously, slightly smokey eyes
3. Deadly hot when they wearing pajamas, their bodies must be sexually perfect.
4. In animation/cartoon/manga, they are always very cool, cannot be getting closed, with good kongfu or killing skills as well.

[image: 01]
[image: 02]
[image: 03]
[image: 04]
[image: 05]
[image: 06]
[image: 07]